# How to wait for all the code in a promise to finish before resolving it? (but a little more complex)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, get

Sorry for the very confusing question, I have this code that gets information from a website without any node modules or libraries. It is a list of users separated into different pages use `?page=` at the end of the URL. I have managed to iterate through the pages and split up the raw HTML just right. However, my promise resolves before all the data is collected. How can I wait for everything to finish before I resolve the promise? I have tried countless solutions, but none seem to work. Please don't ask to use a node package, as my goal is to not use one :) A friend helped with the regex and splitting it up. Here is the code I am using:

```js
function getData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let final = [] //the array of users returned in the end
        const https = require("https"), url = "https://buildtheearth.net/buildteams/121/members";
        https.get(url + "?page=1", request => { //initial request, gets the number of user pages.
            let rawList = '';

            request.setEncoding("utf8"), 
            request.on("data", data => {rawList += data}), 
            request.on("end", () => {
                if(request = (request = (request = rawList.substring(rawList.indexOf('<div class="pagination">'))).substring(0, request.indexOf("</div>"))).match(/<a(.+)>(.+)<\/a>/g)) {
                    for(let t = parseInt(request[request.length - 1].match(/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/g)), a = 1; a < t + 1; a++) { //iterates through member pages
                        https.get(url + "?page=" + a, request2 => { //https request for each page of members
                            let rawList2 = '';
                            
                            request2.setEncoding('utf8'), 
                            request2.on("data", data => {rawList2 += data}), 
                            request2.on("end", () => {
                                let i = rawList2.match(/<td>(.+)<\/td>/g); //finds table in HTML
                                if (i) 
                                    for (var t = 1; t < i.length; t += 3) //iterates through rows in table
                                        console.log(i[t].replace(/<td>/g, "").replace(/<\/td>/g, "")), /* logs element to the console (for testing) */
                                        final.push(i[t].replace(/<td>/g, "").replace(/<\/td>/g, "")); //pushes element to the array that is resolved in the end
                            })
                        })
                        
                    }
                }
                resolve(final) //resolves promise returning final array, but resolves before elements are added with code above
            })
        })
    })
}
```

If this helps, [here](http://www.buildtheearth.net/buildteams/121/members) is the website I am trying to get info from.
I am still a little new to JS so if you could help, I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: I think you are trying to have series of async operation and try to wait until everything finish, There are several ways to do this, ONE IMPORTANT thing, promise is chainable. So you might want to ```PromiseA.then( do something other promise and return it).then(do someting else with your result)``` or if you have array of promises that you don't need particular order , use `promise.all`

Comment: since you resolved the wrong "final" (it's not final at all), you'd get the wrong result. You should only resolve the final after getting all the responses from the second `https.get`, and `promise.all` can do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the help @JoelChu and HoangDao. You can see how I ended up solving it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up turning each action into an async function with a `try` and `catch` block and then chained the functions together with `.then()` For the base (getting data from a website) I took inspiration from an [article on *Medium*](https://medium.com/@gevorggalstyan/how-to-promisify-node-js-http-https-requests-76a5a58ed90c). [Here](https://buildtheearth.net/buildteams/121/members) is the site I am pulling data from, and here is the function to get data from a website:

```js
const getData = async (url) => {
    const lib = url.startsWith('https://') ? https : http;
  
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = lib.get(url, res => {
            if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
                return reject(new Error(`Status Code: ${res.statusCode}`));
            }

            const data = [];

            res.on('data', chunk => data.push(chunk));
            res.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(data).toString()));
        });
  
        req.on('error', reject);
        req.end();
    });
};
```

and then I got the number of pages (which can be accessed by appending `?page=<page number>` to the end of the url) with this this function:

```js
const pages = async () => {
    try {
        let html = await getData('https://buildtheearth.net/buildteams/121/members',);
        let pages = await (html = (html = html.substring(html.indexOf('<div class="pagination">'))).substring(0, html.indexOf("</div>"))).match(/<a(.+)>(.+)<\/a>/g)
        let pageCount = await parseInt(pages[pages.length - 1].match(/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/g))
        return pageCount
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

and then I used the page count to iterate through the pages and add the HTML of each to an array with this function:

```js
const getPages = async pageCount => {
    let returns = []
    try {
        for (page = 1; page <= pageCount; page++) {
            try {
                let pageData = await getData('https://buildtheearth.net/buildteams/121/members?page=' + page)
                returns.push(pageData)
            } catch (error) {
                return error
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    } finally {return returns}
}
```

and then I iterated  through the array of strings of HTML of each page, and extracted the data I needed out of each with this function which would return the list of members I need:

```js
const iteratePages = async pages => {
    if (!Array.isArray(pages)) return
    try {
        let returns = []
        await pages.forEach(page => {
            let list = page.match(/<td>(.+)<\/td>/g);
            if (list)
                for (var element = 1; element < list.length; element += 3)
                    returns.push(list[element].replace(/<td>/g, "").replace(/<\/td>/g, ""));
        })
        return returns
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }   
}
```

And then it was a matter of chaining each together to get the array I needed:

```js
pages().then(pageCount => getPages(pageCount)).then(pages => iteratePages(pages)).then(finalList => {console.log(finalList); console.log(finalList.length)})
```

Comment: Show you another way to deal with looping promises using a more functional programming style.

```js

function chainPromises(initAsyncFunc, ...moreAsyncFunc) {
  return (...args) => (
    moreAsyncFunc
      .reduce((promiseChain, currentTask) => (
         promiseChain
           .then(chainResult => (
              currentTask(chainResult)
           )
         )
      ), Reflect.apply(initAsyncFunc, null, args))
  )
}

```

This way your async function result to pass to the next in the chain until it runs out.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the tip. I will try this out soon 

Comment: The comment section really mess up the code styling. You want to just copy out the bit starting with `function`